# BlackBerry dynamically updating ListField

Tags: blackberry

Is it possible to update BlackBerry `ListField` dynamically?

First I have created a listview with 10 objects, a background service is running in the background to collect the objects, after a while I got few more objects, I want to add these new objects to already existing `ListField` without reloading the MainScreen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, should be possible - add objects to your data structure (for example a Vector) and then call:

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        myList.setSize(myVector.size());
        myList.invalidate();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You change update the backing store where you have the values that are displayed in the list, then call one of the setSize methods on your ListField.