# ListField's method invalidate does not work

Tags: blackberry, java-me, invalidation, listfield

I'm writing a custom list field, but it doesn't not work when i invoke invalidate method. The screen is always empty, while the data of list field is not null or empty!
Please help me figure out the problem.
Thank you in advance

```java
public class FileListField extends ListField implements ListFieldCallback{

    private static final Bitmap fileBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("document.png");
    private static final Bitmap dirBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("emty_folder.png");
    private static final Bitmap addBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("svn_added.png");
    private static final Bitmap delBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("svn_deleted.png");
    private static final Bitmap modBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("svn_modified.png");
    private static final Bitmap novBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("svn_noversion.png");
    private static final Bitmap norBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("svn_normal.png");
    //static Bitmap dowBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("svn_added.png");

    private BigVector bv;

    public FileListField(){
        super();
        bv = new BigVector();
        setCallback(this);
    }

    public void setFileModelVector(BigVector fileModelVector){
        bv.removeAll();
        bv.addElements(fileModelVector.getContiguousArray());
        invalidate();
        System.out.println("ISSSSSSSSSSSSSS CALLLLLLLLLLINNNNNNNG?");
        System.out.println("DISSSPATH?"+UiApplication.isEventDispatchThread());
//      invalidateRange(0, bv.size()-1);
//      FileModel[] fileModelArr = new FileModel[fileModelVector.size()];
//      for(int i=0;i<fileModelVector.size();i++)
//          fileModelArr[i] = (FileModel)fileModelVector.elementAt(i);
//      set(fileModelArr);
    }

    public BigVector getFileModelVector(){
//      BigVector bv = new BigVector();
//      for(int i=0;i<this.getSize();i++)
//          bv.addElement(get(this, i));
        return bv;
    }

    public void set(Object[] or){

    }

    public Object get(ListField list, int index){
        return bv.elementAt(index);
    }

    public int getSize(){
        return bv.size();
    }

    public int indexOfList(ListField listField, String prefix, int start) {
        return getSelectedIndex();
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth(ListField listField) {
        return Display.getWidth();
    }

    public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics graphics
            , int index, int y, int width){
        System.out.println("DRWAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
        FileModel fileModel = (FileModel)get(listField, index);
        if(fileModel.isFile())
            graphics.drawBitmap(0, y, width, fileBitmap.getHeight()
                    , fileBitmap, 0, 0);
        else
            graphics.drawBitmap(0, y, width, dirBitmap.getHeight()
                    , dirBitmap, 0, 0);
        switch(fileModel.getStatus()){
            case FileModel.ADD_STATUS:
                graphics.drawBitmap(0, y, width, addBitmap.getHeight()
                        , addBitmap, 0, 0);
                break;
            case FileModel.DEL_STATUS:
                graphics.drawBitmap(0, y, width,delBitmap.getHeight()
                        , delBitmap, 0, 0);
                break;
            case FileModel.MOD_STATUS:
                graphics.drawBitmap(0, y, width, modBitmap.getHeight()
                        , modBitmap, 0, 0);
                break;
            case FileModel.DOW_STATUS:
                break;
            case FileModel.NOR_STATUS:
                graphics.drawBitmap(0, y, width, norBitmap.getHeight()
                        , norBitmap, 0, 0);
                break;
            default:
                graphics.drawBitmap(0, y, width, novBitmap.getHeight()
                        , novBitmap, 0, 0);
                break;
        }
        graphics.drawText(fileModel.getName(), fileBitmap.getWidth(), y);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think calling `invalidate()` on your `ListField` is enough.  The `invalidate()` call really is a [View layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) method, that indicates that the field must be repainted.  What you are really doing is indicating that the [Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) has changed.

[See this other question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6088484/119114)

Try changing your code to something like this, using setSize():

```
public void setFileModelVector(BigVector fileModelVector){
    bv.removeAll();
    bv.addElements(fileModelVector.getContiguousArray());
    //invalidate();
    setSize(bv.size());
}
```

I also don't know how exactly you're handling ownership of the vector itself, but you could also probably just do this:

```
public void setFileModelVector(BigVector fileModelVector){
    bv = fileModelVector;
    //invalidate();
    setSize(bv.size());
}
```

since you were clearing out the entire vector, then converting the new vector to an array and then adding the array to the original vector.  But, that's a separate issue, and isn't the reason you are seeing an empty `ListField`.

Comment: i tried using setSize, but it throws ArrayIndexOutOfException

Comment: Ok, I think that's actually a **different** problem.  I think this is because you are using `BigVector`.  I believe, if you have a `BigVector`, it's initialized to some size, that assumes you will have a lot of elements (that's why it's called **Big** Vector).  I think `bv.size()` is returning a size that's larger than the number of elements you have actually placed in your vector, assuming that you haven't placed very many in there, yet.  So, you'll need to decide how to rework your code to make sure you properly keep track of the actual vector size.  That's really a different question ...

Comment: @CongNguyen, Try debugging or logging in your code, and print the value of `bv.size()`.  I bet you'll see that it's larger than you think, and that somewhere else (maybe in `bv.elementAt(index)`) you're asking for an element past the end of your actual list.